# Update ng-if variable from ts file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs app written with typescript, I am trying to add an asterisk to a certain field in the html using ng-if

```
<td class="abc" >                    
    <span ng-if="vm.showStar == true && vm.Id == myItem.Id">{{myitem.myValue}}*</span>
    <span ng-if="vm.showStar != true">{{myitem.myValue}}</span>
  </span>
</td>
```

In the ts file, I have what is i guess a javascript function to which i am passing the rootscope in order to capture the event emitted from elsewhere.

```
function myCtrlr(

  $rootScope,

  ...
  $rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(event,data) {
    debugger;
    console.log(event);
    vm.showStar = true;    
});
```

The event is captured successfuly

In the ts file, There is also an interface which contains variables. The interface and javascript function are linked using a line like this:

```
export default angular.module('myapp.controller.hourlyCheck', requires)
  .controller('MyCheckCtrl', myCtrlr)
  .name;
```

But when the event comes in it is not updating the variable showStar in the html. How can I get it to update?

Comment: The first thing that jumps into my eyes is that `vm.showStar` seems to be a boolean value in the controller, however in the view you access it like a method `vm.showStar()`. In angularjs those errors in the templates are often not shown, like you can read [here in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions) under "Forgiving".

Comment: Sorry that was something I had tried just before posting this. I have corrected it. But the end result was the same.